# Conectar DSLITE a wordpress mediante su api para comprar y que se conecte al woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

Quiero conectar DSLite a woocommerce para que los clientes compren y se pueda administrar todo desde woocommerce.

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido, tu pregunta necesita estar enfocada, aparte de eso, parte de las consignas es que muestres que has intentado, puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar tu código y mensajes de error (ambos como texto), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.